# Función que valide que la entrada del usuario sea 0 o 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Debo hacer un while que solo me acepte el ingreso de dos valores, por el momento tengo esto:

```
def ValorCorrecto():
    valorIntroducido = input()
    while(valorIntroducido() != "1" and valorIntroducido.lower() != "0"):
          valorIntrocido = input("Ingrese solo 1 o 0: ")

    return valorIntroducido
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando ingresa un numero distinto, me muestra que solo Ingrese solo 1 o 0, pero esta se sigue mostrando a pesar de que ingrese un valor correcto

Comment: Tienes un error tipogŕafico en `valorIntrocido = input("Ingrese solo 1 o 0: ")`, devería ser `valorIntroducido = input("Ingrese solo 1 o 0: ")`, observa que te falta "du" en "introducido". Por otro lado, `while(valorIntroducido() != "1" and valorIntroducido.lower() != "0")` también es incorrecto, debería ser `while(valorIntroducido.lower() != "1" and valorIntroducido.lower() != "0")` o `while valorIntroducido != "1" and valorIntroducido != "0"`, directamente. Si son errores al escribir el código aquí corrigelos.

Comment: Muchas gracias FJSevilla, estoy seguro que iba a leer el codigo muchas veces y no encontraría ese error

Comment: De nada Sergio, la culpa es de nuestro cerebro que en el fondo es un vago, le encanta deducir a partir de patrones, si  querías escribir "corrección", pero escribiste "correción" lo lees mil veces pero  tu cerebro dice "se que debe poner "corrección", empieza por "co"..., temina en "ón", más o menos tiene el mismo tamaño... ¡Todo bien!  XD . A todos nos ha pasado que lees veinte veces una palabra y no ves la falta....http://albertgascon.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Errores-Simples-e1413052917655.jpg

Comment: Por cierto, bienvenido a [es.so], puedes pasarte por [tour] para conocer por encima el sitio y de paso ganas tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/what-are-badges). Para futuras preguntas, cuando coloques código debes formatearlo como tal para que se vea correctamente, para ello solo tienes que seleccionarlo y pulsar `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor. Dado que todo parece ser un error tipográfico voy a votar por el cierre de la pregunta ya que no será de ayuda a otros usuarios. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Como los string '0' o '1' son numéricos, no tienes que usar el método `lower()`. Además, es mejor usar `not in lista` para comprobar si está dentro de los valores deseados, ya que así no tienes que escribir tantos `and`.

```
def ValorCorrecto():
    valorIntroducido = None
    while valorIntroducido not in ['0','1']:
          valorIntrocido = input("Ingrese solo 1 o 0: ")
    return valorIntroducido
```